# Searches for finding questions that need attention

Tags: discussion, voting, unanswered-questions

This post is intended to be a place to collect queries to help find questions that could use some attention. Maybe they need another answer, maybe the answers need to be voted on, or maybe the question just needs a little editing to make it clearer.

I will add a community wiki for helpful searches that are already written. If you can think of other searches that might be helpful, add an answer explaining what characteristics you would like to search for, and maybe some of our data explorer experts will be able to make it happen.

The data that the queries search is not "real time"; it is updated every Sunday so it won't return posts less than a week old.

Comment: You can also search for `title:correct` or `title:meaning` to find questions with bad titles that potentially have a problem in the body or tags too.

Comment: @Rubisco Finally, a use for [tag:grammar] :) I added a regular search (not data explorer) for 'correct' in the title and [tag:grammar]. It looks like there are a bunch of questions in there that could use work.

Comment: OK, you might've noticed that I play with pronunciation questions quite a lot. There are lots and lots of duplicates of the same question. I sometimes bump them by editing and vote-to-close-as-duplicate, but no one closes them, so they remain opened. I wonder if I could post them here so they can be closed as duplicates. /// There are other questions that are truly out of kilter with the site's ethos (i.e. atrocious questions without any research or context) but have useful answers. And most of the time, there are duplicates, IMO, we should merge those answers with the ones given to the dups

Comment: @Void If you need help from the community getting questions handled, it’s completely appropriate to post on Meta. I did see your duplicates and voted on them, but it will take some time for them to get 5 votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Questions with zero score and more than 2 answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1819362/zero-score-questions-with-multiple-answers)
(Questions need upvotes too. If a question stimulated multiple answers, it may be worth upvoting.)

[Image in the post is missing a description](http://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/235921/posts-containing-images-without-alt-text)
(Adding alt text to images is important to make the site accessible, and helps the answer be useful when the image is inaccessible for some reason. Add a term to the "special mention" field to see a check by posts with that term - try 'NGram').

[Open questions with only one broad tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/368033/nonclosed-questions-with-only-one-broad-tag)
(Suggested tags: grammar, meaning, usage)

[High views, up-voted, multiple answers, no accepted answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/552574/high-views-up-voted-multiple-answers-no-accepted-answer)
(Author may need to be reminded to accept an answer)

[High views per day questions with few answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/512694/high-views-per-day-questions-with-few-answers)
(Question may need clarification, or another answer or two)

[Highly voted questions with few or no answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/550701/highly-voted-questions-with-few-or-no-answers)
(Needs more answers, or perhaps a bounty)

[Upvoted questions with no answers and low views](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/550704/upvoted-questions-with-no-answers-and-low-views?score=0)
(Needs more answers, or perhaps a bounty)

[Questions with lots of answers, but none upvoted](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/503035/questions-with-lots-of-answers-but-none-upvoted)
(Answers need to be refined or a better answer provided)

[Questions tagged with grammar and 'correct' in the title](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgrammar%5D%20title%3Acorrect)
(Question probably needs editing and tagging)

[Questions migrated from ELU](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/485239/migrated-questions-from-elu-with-scores-less-than-parameter?StartDate=09%2F22%2F2015&MaximumScore=1&MinimumScore=-1)
(You can set the score range and date - try using score 0 to find questions that might not have gotten enough attention)

[Find interesting unanswered questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/4038/find-interesting-unanswered-questions)
(Looks at unanswered questions in your top 20 tags and sorts them by a combined weight which takes into account: score, askers reputation and how
well you do on that particular tag)

Comment: Once we click on those, what do we do next? Not everyone understands it. Like me, I don't.

Comment: @Lambie The ones that are on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) are database queries, so you would need to fill in any parameters and click "Run Query". It will make you solve a captcha if you aren't logged in. Logging in is kind of clunky because it takes you away from the query you want to run (It seems like it's supposed to take you back to the page you were on, but it never works for me). I go to https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login and login with my Stack exchange account (Click "Login using Stack Overflow"), then click the links here so I don't have to fill out the captchas.