# How exactly can I earn the Organizer badge?

Tags: support, tags, badges

I'm sorry for asking again, but I have no choice. I tried to ask in chat, but it did not help.
I do not know how to earn Organizer badge. I understand I must do something with tags. I tried to add, delete or change the tags in my own questions several times. But no badge until now.
If anyone explains me how to earn this badge, I will be very grateful.

Comment: **Please** don't retag questions just to earn a badge. If you are going to retag a question, do it because it **needs** to be retagged. In other words, make sure you find a question that is improperly tagged before you retag it.

Comment: OK, I've understood you.

Comment: There is a post with some searches that will help you find questions that could use some editing: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3248/ We are trying to edit questions with just the [tag:grammar] tag to add more helpful tags, so that might be a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [canonical, site-wide FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/273503) listing all the badges and how to earn them:

> #### Organizer
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Retag a question **asked by another user (not your own question)**

Please check that FAQ for any future questions on how to earn badges.