# filter for questions

Tags: discussion, search

I want to create a special (over)view for questions. I think of at least the following:

- no answers at all (or, alternatively, with answer(s) but no accepted answer);
- not closed (for whatever reason);
- sorted (newest to oldest, or alternatively, oldest to newest);
- specific community.

I am aware of data.stackexchange.com, but:

- I cannot create a filter at all - where can I find a "manual";
- I did not see any option for sorting.

Thank you for your kind support.

Comment: Related: [Searches that might help you find questions that need attention](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3248/9161)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Exchange searches return a URL that you can bookmark. There is a post with [some tips for searching](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4883/9161) in the Contributor's Guide that's a good start. For more advanced searches, there is the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) site, but the data there is delayed by a day and we don't need to write SQL for most searches.

- To find questions that don't have an accepted answer use `isanswered:no`
- To find questions with a certain number of answers use `answers:#`. If you want questions with no answers, use `answers:0`. Add '..' to specify a range. For example, `answers:..1` will return questions with 1 or fewer answers.
- To exclude questions that have been closed, use `closed:no`.
- To sort a search, use the buttons at the top of the page:

  - Newest sorts by when the question was created
  - Frequent is a list of questions that have links, sorted by the number of links
  - Votes sorts by score
  - Active sorts by the last time the question or an answer to it was edited or posted. Comments do not affect the "active" time.
  - Unanswered is a list of questions with no up-voted answers (there may be some with accepted answers, but all answers will be scored zero or less).
- To search a specific community, just navigate to that community and enter your search there. To search across all communities, use the search on [the main Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/). There is a ["filter" feature](https://stackexchange.com/filters/161071/my-filter) but it just filters on tags. There is also a [Custom Question List alpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323202/273494) that you can participate in.

Here is a search URL for questions that haven't been closed with no answers and more than 500 views (so we can find the neglected ones, not just the brand new ones):
[`https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0%20closed%3ano%20views%3a500..`](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3A0%20closed%3Ano%20views%3A500..)

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. I used the following string, based on the info from you (slightly different than your examples): **"answers:0 closed:no duplicate:no score:1.."** Do you think it does any good?

Comment: @virolino If it helps you find the types of questions you’re looking for, it’s good :)